# Determine if columns of a pandas dataframe uniquely identify the rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to determine if a column or set of columns of a pandas dataframe uniquely identifies the rows of that dataframe. I've seen this called the [`isid` function in Stata.](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/disid.pdf)

The best I can think of is to get the unique values of a subset of columns using a set comprehension, and asserting that there are as many values in the set as there are rows in the dataframe:

```
subset = df[["colA", "colC"...]]
unique_vals = {tuple(x) for x in subset.values}
assert(len(unique_vals) == len(df))
```

This isn't the most elegant answer in the world, so I'm wondering if there's a built-in function that does this, or perhaps a way to test if a subset of columns are a uniquely-valued index.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could make an index and check its `is_unique` attribute:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(1,2)], columns=list('AB'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(1,3)], columns=list('AB'))

print(df1.set_index(['A','B']).index.is_unique)
# False

print(df2.set_index(['A','B']).index.is_unique)
# True
```

Comment: huh, I thought maybe this would be slower than using duplicated, but in a handful of test cases this was always faster (not dramatically faster, but clearly faster in each case I tried)

Answer (score 3):

You can check

```
df[['x', 'y']].transform(tuple,1).duplicated(keep=False).any()
```

To see if there are any duplicated rows with the sets of value from columns `x` and `y`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,4], 'y': ["a", "b", "c", "d","d"]})


    x   y
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   4   d
4   4   d
```

Then `transform`

```
0    (1, a)
1    (2, b)
2    (3, c)
3    (4, d)
4    (4, d)
dtype: object
```

then check which are `duplicated()`

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Notice that `transforming` into `tuple` might not be necessary

```
df.duplicated(keep=False)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: simpler way (or at least more concise) might be `(~df.duplicated()).all()`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `groupby` `size`

```
df.groupby(['x','y']).size()==1
Out[308]: 
x  y
1  a     True
2  b     True
3  c     True
4  d    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Adding `.all()` to the end would give you a simple boolean that tells if the columns are an index. Nice answer!

Comment: Warning, this doesn't work with nan values

Comment: @CameronChandler switch to count , will work